# Windows agents implementation

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-services, agent

One creates a Windows agent by calling [CreateService](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682450(v=vs.85).aspx) with one of the following two parameters: `SERVICE_USER_OWN_PROCESS` or `SERVICE_USER_SHARE_PROCESS`. When `SERVICE_USER_OWN_PROCESS` is used, the agent will start with the next login and it will have a name like < service_name>_< some session ID>. Example of Windows 10 Microsoft agents: MessagingService_ba3d3c, PrintWorkflowUserSvc_ba3d3c or DevicesFlowUserSvc_ba3d3c (call `sc query type=userservice` to see the active ones) - in this case, the `<session ID>` is 0xba3d3c, while the Logon Session is 0xba1a53 (close, but not enough) (seen with `Process explorer`).

My questions are:

1. Can I start the agent immediately after installation without logout? It would help with the installer that asks for reboot now.
2. What is this mysterious "session ID" ? It would help with the testing, to avoid enumeration and guessing.

Comment: Apparently there's no publicly documented way to start a user service given just the base template name. FWIW, with a breakpoint set on `ScCreateUserServicesForUser` in services.exe, I see it gets called via RPC from some process that calls `I_ScBroadcastServiceControlMessage` in sechost.dll. The user context ID (e.g. 0xba3d3c) is passed as the first parameter. I tracked its source to the User Manager service. It can be queried by calling `UMgrQueryUserContext` in usermgrcli.dll, with a handle for the user token and a pointer to an LUID (i.e. `ULONGLONG`) that receives the user context ID.

Comment: The similarity to the logon session ID is most likely due to these services (LSA and User Manager) calling `NtAllocateLocallyUniqueId` within a narrow time window. It's just based on a counter in the kernel.

Comment: @eryksun so, for 2 you suggest using using something like `LsaEnumerateLogonSessions` or `LsaGetLogonSessionData` to find that context ID ? And once 2 is solved, can I use this full name with StartService for 1 (even if I doubt the service is known by the current session) ?

Comment: I don't see a public API that creates the user service instance (i.e. calls `ScCreateUserServicesForUser` in services.exe). There could be; I just I haven't seen anything written about this new type of service. That said, if you have the name of the service for the current user, you can at least open it, stop it, restart it, etc. Again, to get the context LUID, call the User Manager's `UMgrQueryUserContext` function with a handle for the user's token; it's not related to the logon session ID. I think sechost.dll also exports a function to get the complete instance name.

Comment: @eryksun 1) "if you have the name of the service for the current user"  how can I have it? I mean `PrintWorkflowUserSvc_4595e`, no `PrintWorkflowUserSvc` Now, I enumerate services and I am guessing. 2) "call the User Manager's UMgrQueryUserContext function" ... how can I call a function not exported ?

Comment: As I said, it's exported by the User Manager client library, usermgrcli.dll. `UMgrQueryUserContext` handles the RPC call to the User Manager service for you. That said, apparently sechost.dll (which implements the service API) exports undocumented functions to get the instance name -- `QueryLocalUserServiceName`, `QueryUserServiceName`, and `QueryUserServiceNameForContext`. I haven't experimented with calling them.

Comment: @eryksun thank you, but désolé, I do not find any UMgrQueryUserContext

Comment: There's no header declaration or import library. You have to use it dynamically via `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress`.